# What is the difference between this.value and this->value?

Tags: c++

I just started studying C++, and I met this new guy: ->. I was wondering if it means something different than (.) or not, and if it does, what it is.

Can you answer that? I looked for it a bit, but I didn´t find anything to answer my question.

Comment: You must not have looked very hard. ;-)

Comment: Nit: `this->value` is syntactically valid, `this.value` is not since `this` is a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start with a pointer to an object, use `->`. If you start with a reference or direct value of class type, use `.`. If you use the wrong one, the compiler should give a pretty clear error message.

`a->b` is defined to be synonymous with `(*a).b`.

Except in the case of operator overloading, in which case `->` and `*` must be overloaded separately, and `.` cannot be overloaded.

Comment: `*a` can also be overridden, but `a.` cannot.

Comment: @Merlyn yeah, fixed… the situation isn't really that asymmetrical.

Comment: this.value is not a valid expression.

Comment: @chubsdad: where did that come from?

Answer (score 0):

You use `.` when you're working with an object, and `->` when you're working with a pointer to an object.  `->` 'dereferences' the pointer (i.e. provides access to the underlying object).